# Definition of polynomial (LG[Hoffman]

Tags: linear-algebra

In chapter 4.2 of Hoffman&Kunze's Linear Algebra "The Algebra of Polynomials"

Theorem 1. Let f and g be non-zero polynomials over F. Then

1. fg is a non-zero polynomial
2. deg(fg)=deg(f)+deg(g)
3. fg is a monic polynomial if both f and g are monic polynomials.

In his proof:

Suppose f has degree m and that g has degree n n. If k is a non-negative integer,

$$(fg)_{m+n+k}=\sum_{i=0}^{m+n+k}f_ig_{m+n+k-i}$$ In order that $f_ig_{m+n+k-i}\ne 0$ it is necessary that $i\le m$ and $m+n+k-i\le n$. Hence that $m+k\le i\le m$ which implies $k=0$ and $i=m$. Thus

$$(fg)_{m+n+k}=\sum_{i=0}^{m+n+k}f_mg_n$$

and $$(fg)_{m+n+k}=0, k>0$$

I dont understand this proof. In his notation if f is a polynomial of degree n then:

$$F=f_0x^0+f_1x+f_2x^2+.....+f_nx^n$$

So $(fg)_{m+n+k}$ is supposed to mean the $(m+n+k)th$ term of the polynomial product of f and g, where f has degree m and g has degree n? I dont know how this makes any sense....

Later in Chapter 4.4  he gave the folllowing definition of an ideal:

Let F be a field. An ideal in F[x] is a subspace M of F[X] such that fg belongs to M whenever f is in F[x] and g is in M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(fg)_{m+n+k}$ is indeed supposed to mean the $(m+n+k)$’th coefficient, under the convention that $(p)_j$ exists for every $j$, but is just $0$ for all but finitely many of these $j$. This makes the notation nice, usually. Here, it is my strong opinion that that proof was too formal for its own good.

You can observe that a degree $m$ and a degree $n$ polynomial cannot have coefficients of a higher order than $n+m$ since the degree of a term $a_n x^n\cdot b_m x^m$ is just $x^{n+m}$, and the largest numbers you’re allowed to combine are $m$ and $n$... so your intuition that it doesn’t make any sense is essentially right. We just pretend we can write $(p)_j$ for any $j$ as it’s convenient (e.g. I can write $(p)_{100}$ for a quadratic... whether that “makes sense” (morally) is up to you, but mathematically there is no problem so long as I say $(p)_{100}=0$).

Comment: You making me feel bad here....answering my questions like this. Hey I am actually a huge fan of maths and Im really curious as to how you learn maths as a 12th year. Could you add me on Skype and maybe i can pick your brain sometimes?   Skype: jerry22292

Comment: @Tomy I’ll have to think about that carefully. I am however always happy to talk in comments or MSE chatrooms (or Discord)

Comment: Ouh discord would be great too, i mean here on MSE would be off topic and probably anooying for others https://discord.gg/zVYSbq3P